# Google PageSpeed: Big gap between Desktop and Mobile

Tags: performance, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I'm trying to improve/optimize my website performance and cannot make it work.. And I running out of ideas.

This is my Site in Desktop with 99/100 score.
[image]

And this is my website performance in Mobile, with 40/100 score.

[image]

There are some big differences in server stuff, no idea why or how to improve this..

Thanks.

Edit: Site URL: [creatufrase.net](https://creatufrase.net)

Comment: post a site url

Comment: @Evgeniy https://creatufrase.net

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main big difference in the new Google PageSpeed is on the way how the Desktop and Mobile is tested, where on Mobile is applied internet connection limits and slowed down CPU.

Currently, Lighthouse (Google PageSpeed) [simulates a page load](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about#faq) on a mid-tier device (Moto G4) on a mobile network. With these following [network limits](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/throttling.md):

- Latency: 150ms
- Throughput: 1.6Mbps down / 750 Kbps up.
- Packet loss: none.

As well, the mobile device is with slowed down CPU power.

In this case, if your website is JavaScript heavy then lower CPU powered mobile devices parse and process JavaScript much slower and the network limits slow down overall speed if you have a large website with large images or other elements.

As I can't find official confirmation, I'm guessing that desktop tests are tested without these limits and that for some website could make a huge difference between mobile and desktop data in the new Google PageSpeed tests. Especially, if your website is a bit with more JS or contains heavy images.

For confirmation about these limits I did a quick test using Lighthouse Audit tool in the Google Chrome Dev Tools and used for mobile network and slowed down CPU limits, but for desktop didn't apply any limits and I got similar timing results as in Google PageSpeed mobile vs desktop.

Based on all this information, have a closer look at your script usage under *Reduce JavaScript execution time*. Start with reviewing ad/tracking scripts, *Add This* widget and other 3rd party scripts.